# Unable to Add Non-Steam Game to Library

Tags: steam

[image: 'No Such Interface Supported']

When I try to add Bionic Commando: Rearmed (purchased via [GamersGate](http://www.gamersgate.com/)) to Steam, I get the following error message:

> No such interface supported

What the heck does *that* mean?  And is there a workaround?

---

This may or may not be relevant, but the Gamersgate installer installed the game to the 'windows games' directory, which seems to behave differently from the rest of the system.

This is what I see when I view the shortcut properties:

[image: Shortcut Properties]

**EDIT:**

Here is a very informative [chat conversation](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2755938#2755938) that should give you lots of more information about this that I can't be bothered to accurately record here.

Comment: From what I'm seeing, I think that's a Windows error, not a Steam error. Haven't seen a fix yet though.

Comment: That is pretty strange - I've added all kinds of stuff (Visual Studio 2010, etc.) as a game without an issue.

Comment: Have you tried any other non-Steam games?  As a side note to programmers out there, write informative error messages.

Comment: So far, the fixes I've seen for that error involve registering different .dll files. Unfortunately the .dll to register seems different for each fix.

Comment: @MBraedley Yes, I have *loads* of non-steam games in my library.

Comment: @GnomeSlice but have you tried another one recently?  I'm sure you've updated your Steam client in the past couple of days.  That might be the cause.

Comment: @MBraedley Nope, just added one fine.

Comment: Which OS you have installed?

Comment: When you registered the game, was it auto-located, or did you have to click Browse first?

Comment: does any one know if there is any heavy handed DRM on Bionic Commando or on GamersGate downloads?

Comment: also, if you can go to where the shortcut for the game is located, right click on it and go to properties. is there any thing after the locate in the "Target" box? e.g "c:\path\to\game" -foobar

Comment: Games come with all kinds of different DRM from Gamersgate.  I've successfully added other games downloaded from there to my Steam library.  Strange though, Bionic Commando [doesn't even list a DRM](http://www.gamersgate.com/DD-BCR/bionic-commando-rearmed)...

Comment: Maybe try creating a shortcut to the shortcut... then adding that

Comment: is it normal for the target line to be uneditable? i know i can edit all of mine.
i think you should try @oak 's idea.

Comment: Non-Steam games that us launchers or spawn new Windows processes also often don't work. They'll launch, but Steam won't say you're still in game if the original executable launched by Steam doesn't stay active.

Comment: That sounds like what may be happening here, although the game doesn't even run.  If I try downloading and adding the .dll file that the -mce shortcut says is missing when I try to run it via steam, the game's splash screen opens, but the game crashes shortly after.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Locate the .exe of your game, right click it, Send To -> Desktop Shortcut and add that one to Steam.

Also, BC:R requires adminstrator privildeges to run ([this screenshot](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2756046#2756046) of yours suggests this), so you may have to run Steam as admin.

(I don't know if Steam respects a shortcut that is set to run as admin or whether this can be set somehow)

Comment: I've done that, and what happens is that Steam briefly (few seconds) says I'm in the game, and then reverts to 'online' status.  The game never actually opens.

Comment: is there any output if you start the .exe via a command shell?

Comment: @GnomeSlice maybe BC:R requires adminstrator privildeges to run ([this screenshot](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2756046#2756046) of yours suggests this), so can you try running Steam as admin? (I don't know if Steam respects a shortcut that is set to run as admin)

Comment: @TobiasKienzler That worked!  Edit that into your answer, please.  :D

Comment: @GnomeSlice Sure, done. Maybe it is sufficient to set the BC desktop shortcut to "Run as administrator" and re-add it to Steam so you don't have to grant Steam to many rights. Or Moving BC somewhere else but \program files\

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you can only add Windows shortcuts to the Steam games list.

Sadly, not all games are compatible with it, but usually you don't get an error; instead pressing shift-tab in game just does nothing.

Comment: It IS a Windows shortcut.  This may or may not be relevant, but the Gamersgate installer installed the game to the 'windows games' directory, which seems to behave differently from the rest of the system.